# Determine all $z$ so it satisfies given equation

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Determine all values of complex number $z$ such that it satisfies $\sin z = 2$

Should I transform $z = x + iy$ in that equation so I can get more complex things. Please help me, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what should $\exp(iz)$ be?

Comment: $\cos z + i~\sin z$?

Comment: And if $\sin z = 2$, that is...

Comment: $\cos z + 2i$?  What equation must be satisfied?

Comment: What is $\cos z$ if $\sin z = 2$?

Comment: $\cos z = \sqrt{3}i$.

Comment: Actually $\pm \sqrt{3} i$.  So that makes $\exp(iz) = \ldots$